# Обновление экрана в JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Делаю секундомер, но время меняется только после обновления экрана. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы скрипт обновлялся автоматически через определеный период времени?

```
function printDate2() {
    today = new Date();
    Time = today.getSeconds();
    document.write('<p >' + Time + '</p>');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если использовать jQuery, то:

```
<div id="updateMe">...</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>

function updateTime() {
    today = new Date();
    $('#updateMe').html('Time: ' + today.getSeconds() );
    setTimeout(function() {updateTime();}, 1000);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    updateTime();
});
</script>
```

Если коротко, то: функции setTimeout и setInterval (и сlearInterval) в JS.

Answer (score 3):

html

```
<p id="time"></p>
```

js

```
var timer = document.getElementById('time');

setInterval(function () {
    today = new Date();
    Time = today.getSeconds();
    timer.innerHTML = Time;
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Запускайте секундомер на событие "Страница полностью загружена". Вот пример кроссбраузерного решения:

```
function init() {
if (arguments.callee.done) return;
arguments.callee.done = true;

// ваш код здесь
}

// ff, opera
if (document.addEventListener) {
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);
}

// ie
/*@cc_on @*/
/*@if (@_win32)
document.write("<script id=__ie_onload defer src=javascript:void(0)>");
document.write("<\/script>");
var script = document.getElementById("__ie_onload");
script.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == "complete") {
    init();
}
};
/*@end @*/

// safari
if (/WebKit/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
var _timer = setInterval(function() {
    if (/loaded|complete/.test(document.readyState)) {
        clearInterval(_timer);
        delete _timer;
        init();
    }
}, 10);
}

// others
window.onload = init;
```

или просто повесьте функцию на

```
<body onload="printDate2();">
```